# mysqli fetch array displays only the first row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written this code:

```
require("config.php");

$rows = array();

$query = "SELECT accountname, bill_city, bill_code, bill_country,  bill_street, latitude, longitude, setype FROM vtiger_accountbillads, vtiger_account, vtiger_geocoding WHERE accountaddressid = accountid AND accountid = crmid";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$rows_number = $result->num_rows;
echo $rows_number . "<br/><br/>";

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    for($i=0; $i < $rows_number; $i++) {
            $rows[] = array("name" => $row[0],
                        "city" => $row[1],
                        "code" => $row[2],
                        "country" => $row[3],
                        "street" => $row[4],
                        "latitude" => $row[5],
                        "longitude" => $row[6],
                        "type" => $row[7]);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($rows);
print $json;

mysqli_free_result($row);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I'm trying to fetch several data using the query written in the code above, but it displays the first row 47 times. Why? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you should use foreach instead of for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the result set returned by MySQL. That means calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` for each row of that result set. You can do that using a `while` loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = array("name"      => $row['name'],
                    "city"      => $row['bill_city'],
                    "code"      => $row['bill_code'],
                    "country"   => $row['bill_country'],
                    "street"    => $row['bill_street'],
                    "latitude"  => $row['latitude'],
                    "longitude" => $row['longitude'],
                    "type"      => $row['setype']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've modified the code as you suggested but now it displays nothing, and I cannot understand why, because the number of rows returned is greater than 0..

Comment: If you put `var_dump($row)` in this while loop, what do you see?

Comment: something like this: `array(16) { [0]=> string(10) "Google Spa" ["name"]=> string(10) "Google Spa" [1]=> string(10) "Vicenza" ["bill_city"]=> string(10) "Vicenza" [2]=> string(5) "36100" ["bill_code"]=> string(5) "36100" [3]=> string(6) "Italia" ["bill_country"]=> string(6) "Italia" [4]=> string(13) "Via Firenze 400" ["bill_street"]=> string(13) "Via Firenze 400" [5]=> string(9) "45.643455" ["latitude"]=> string(9) "45.643455" [6]=> string(9) "11.497678" ["longitude"]=> string(9) "11.497678" [7]=> string(15) "Geolocalization" ["setype"]=> string(15) "Geolocalization" }` 47 times

Comment: Ok, that's good. That means you're retrieving your data ok. I updated my answer to populate your array. Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: If you do `var_dump($rows)` after this loop, do you get date?

Comment: Ok, then the problem isn't with this code. It's somewhere after this.

Comment: I doubt it as that function is built in and straight forward. It could be the array isn't in a format you need or the javascript that consumes it isn't working.

Comment: I have found the problem: I have changed the coding of the database to  `utf8_general_ci` and now it works!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use for `loop` for fetching SQL queries. Use `while` instead:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = array("name" => $row[0],
                        "city" => $row[1],
                        "code" => $row[2],
                        "country" => $row[3],
                        "street" => $row[4],
                        "latitude" => $row[5],
                        "longitude" => $row[6],
                        "type" => $row[7]);
    }
}
```